# Why do we need a pull-up resitor and not directly tie the pin to 5V (Arduino)?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm not very good at analog circuits. So the question is:

Besides the floating pin problem, why do we need a pull-up resistor? Why can't we tie the pin directly to 5V?
I'm reading up on it and am getting mixed answers. One website said that it's to limit the current flow when the button is pressed so that it doesn't fry the board.
On a different forum, someone said that the current isn't the problem since the input resistance of the pin is high enough that it shouldn't matter.
Which one of these is correct? I feel like there's a gap in my understanding somewhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove the `A Digital Logic Gate` from both circuits ... now examine the circuits carefully ... what problem do you see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the pull up resistor, the 5V supply will be shorted to ground when either of the input switch "a" and "b" are closed. This can result in damage to 5V supply or the 5V supply will be turned off if over current protection feature is used in 5V supply.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two answers for two different situations.  In your first picture, you can see that pressing either of the buttons will short 5V to ground and fry your board.  In the second picture, with the resistors, the current is limited to 5/R.  In either of these cases, the input impedance of the Arduino doesn't come into play.  Atmel designed the chip to tolerate up to VCC + 0.5V at any of the pins (except RESET), so there is no need to provide additional protection unless you are planning on exceeding this voltage and even then it's a better idea to use an external network.